# Rails 6 app not reading ENV on Heroku during tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, heroku, environment-variables

I have a Rails 6 app deployed to Heroku and working fine. I've just started adding an API to the app, and this is also working fine locally, with all tests passing locally.

When I deploy to Heroku, the app responds correctly to curl.

However, my tests (running via Heroku CI) are failing with `TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String` during authorisation of the JWT token. I've identified the root cause, which is that the `DEVISE_JWT_SECRET_KEY` environment variable isn't being loaded for my tests.

This variable is defined as a Heroku environment variable, and works fine when I test the actual app using curl, as I mentioned. Running

```rb
heroku config:get DEVISE_JWT_SECRET_KEY -a [APP_NAME]
```

returns the correct key.

When I add a line to my tests to check for the variable, the `raise` is executed when the tests run, showing that the variable is missing.

```rb
raise if ENV['DEVISE_JWT_SECRET_KEY'].nil?
```

Can anyone suggest why environment variables aren't loading when I run my tests on Heroku?

Comment: Protip is to use `ENV.fetch('DEVISE_JWT_SECRET_KEY')` which will raise a KeyError on nil.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to "However, my tests are failing" part - you're running your unit tests on heroku?

Comment: @max I'm running integration tests on Heroku, using the Heroku CI system on my Pipeline. This is the use case for which Heroku CI is designed.

Comment: I missed the CI part - I thought you where just trying to run them off the heroku runner in your production environment. That would be bad news.

Comment: For reference, @max, I made the change to use `ENV.fetch()` in the devise initializer, and this fails with a KeyError during initialization as you'd expect - but only on HerokuCI running the tests, not when I restart the dyno itself. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note that unlike review apps, Heroku CI does not inherit any config
> vars from the parent app.
>
> To set confidential or volatile environment variables (such as access
> tokens) that you shouldn’t include in app.json, you can instead add
> them to your pipeline’s Heroku CI settings in the Heroku Dashboard.
>
> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci

So it would be wrong to expect your CI to use the config vars you set through the CLI and that could potentially lead to some really serious problems if your CI for example used real third party credentials by mistake.

Comment: I haven't actually used heroku CI but if it uses a separate RAILS_ENV variable you could also use the encrypted secrets mechanism in Rails since Rails 6 has per environment encrypted secrets.

Comment: Aha - that was it, thanks @max! When I updated all my Heroku instances with the new DEVISE_JWT_SECRET_KEY, I'd missed the Pipeline CI config section. (Probably not a great idea to put secret keys into the app.json file, even for a test environment.) Adding a key to the Pipeline's environment means that the test now pass. Thanks 